# Chromebook kiosk mode, disable switch to ChromeOS

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, kiosk, google-chrome-os

When kiosk app starts on Chromebook it shows message "Switch to ChromeOS by pressing "**CTRL-ALT-S**" keys. 
I would like to disable posibility to switch to ChromeOS, I just want to run kiosk app on the `Chromebook.

Kiosk mode is set on Google Admin Console, app that starts automatically is specified and all works OK. However during ChromeOS bootup, there is for a 5 sec option to switch to ChromeOS by pressing CTRL-ALT-S" keys.

Is there a way to disable this option to switch to ChromeOS on Google Admin Console?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I believe answer is found, this is apparently a Chrome feature request:

Issue 552451: FR: Ability to disable keyboard shortcuts for Single App Kiosk mode.

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=552451